# Laravel cache facade

Tags: php, laravel, caching, eloquent

I am using cache facade and I am wondering if I am using it in the right way because I cannot see any performance improvement. Is this correct:

```
$requirements = Cache::remember('requirements', 30/60, function() use($lang) {
             return Requirement::with([
                                'countryMatch',
                                'applier',
                                'doc.translation' => function ($query) use ($lang){ $query->where('language',$lang);}
                        ])->get();
        });


return $this->showAll($requirements);
```

Answer (score 0):

To put data into cache, use 'put' method:

```
Cache::put( 'requirements', function() use($lang) {
         return Requirement::with([
                            'countryMatch',
                            'applier',
                            'doc.translation' => function ($query) use ($lang){ $query->where('language',$lang);}
                    ])->get(); 
}, 30 / 60);
```

Comment: I think is the same as remember function

Comment: Put will just add something to the cache, remember will return the currently cached item if there is one. if there isn’t it runs the closure and puts that in the cache for future requests